# Audio extracted gets accelerated in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, video, extract

I am trying to extract audio from video and store it in a file using matlab

```
file = 'E:\test\Kepler1.avi';
file1 = 'E:\test\audiofile.wav';
hmfr = video.MultimediaFileReader(file,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
hmfw = video.MultimediaFileWriter(file1,'AudioInputPort',true,'VideoInputPort',false,'FileFormat','WAV');
while ~isDone(hmfr)
  audioFrame = step(hmfr);
  step(hmfw,audioFrame);
end
release(hmfw);
release(hmfr);
audio_samples = wavread(file1);
```

The problems i am facing are:

1. It does not work for all video files i.e. it may work for one avi file but not for other. Haven't tested for other formats till now.
2. The video for which it works , the audio file created is accelerated i.e. for 30 sec video the output is of 8 sec but accelerated.

What are the possible solution to the problem? Is there any other way to do this in matlab itself?

P.S.: I am using matlab *R2012a* version.

Comment: Don't you need to set the sample rate for the MultimediaFileWriter?

Comment: I an not aware of it.. I thought the step will handle it and rate will be that of default video one itself.

Comment: I'm just guessing based on the example at http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/signalblks.multimediafilewriter-class.html that the sample rate does not get propagated.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, this link should be useful - https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/323911-how-to-get-the-audio-signal-from-a-video

For second question - it is a sample rate issue. While reading wav and other audio formats, MATLAB return the same sampling rate as the wav file. However, that doesn't seem to be the case here. Get the sample rate of the original file (can be obtained by reading the audio file corresponding to the video) by using https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioinfo.html. Then, when you are 'writing' audio to an external format, you can use -

```
audiowrite(filename,y,Fs)
```

Where Fs is the sampling frequency. If it's the same as your source file, the output will be of same length and not 'accelerated'.